# Initialize standard container of unique pointers in base constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, containers, unique-ptr

What would be the preferred way to initialize a Standard Library Container of unique pointers in a base constructor, given that the container and its contents are known at compile time? C++ does not allow initializer lists to be used with unique pointers, since they force a copy operation, so I'm currently using an ugly lambda workaround:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std; // Note: for readability only

// Some non-POD object
class Object {
public: 
    Object(const string& desc) : description(desc) { }
    string description;
    void func () { /* do stuff */ }
};

// This class stores a vector of unique pointers to objects
class BaseX {
public:
    const vector< unique_ptr<const Object> > objects;
    BaseX (vector< unique_ptr<Object> > vec) : 
        objects { make_move_iterator(vec.begin()), make_move_iterator(vec.end()) } { }
};

// This class is a special case of BaseX where the object definitions are constant, and known at compile time (static).
// Question is how to initialize them...
class DerivedX : public BaseX {
public:
    DerivedX () : BaseX(
        // Using a lambda function is a messy idea, but works
        []()->vector< unique_ptr<Object> > {
            unique_ptr<Object> objects[] = {
                make_unique<Object>("My object")
            };
            return { make_move_iterator(begin(objects)), make_move_iterator(end(objects)) };
        }()
    ) { }
};
```

This seems like a case where `static` something should be used, but not sure where it fits in...

Comment: The STL is an old library that doesn't know about move semantics. Parts of the C++ Standard Library are based on the STL.

Comment: I'd argue that `BaseX` should not take a `vector<..>` but more generally either a range (generic function parameter) or a pair of iterators. There's no need to allocate memory twice in this example.

Comment: *"This seems like a case where static something should be used,"* It is certainly possible to use a static member function instead of a lambda-expression: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8db6b0bb9fd45a6

Comment: I'd suggest using a tuple as opposed to a vector if your elements are known at compile time. Tuples support move semantics.

Comment: @dyp Good point on the memory alloc. Sorry about the STL confusion, I must have misunderstood the naming. As for the static member function, I can't believe I didn't think of that... It makes more sense than using a lambda, I think.

Comment: @ChristianBlume Interesting idea, I wouldn't have thought of tuples as a good container for same-type elements. Aren't they much heavier than a vector?

Comment: It's not necessary to use an array and then range-construct from that, you can just make the body of the lambda (or static function) create an empty vector, call reserve, then emplace_back into it.

Comment: Why would tuple be heavier than a vector? it's just like std::pair only not restricted to two elements. that means the elements aren't on the heap, unlike vector, but if that matters use `unique_ptr<tuple<blah, blah, blah>>`. Since the elements are all the same type, `array<blah, N>` might make more sense than `tuple<blah, blah, blah>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just do:

```
class DerivedX : public BaseX {
public:
  DerivedX () : BaseX(make_vec()) { }

private:
  static auto make_vec()
  {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const O>> v(2);
    v[0] = std::make_unique<O>("1");
    v[1] = std::make_unique<O>("2");
    return v;
  }
};
```

(Using the `auto` return type, since you seem to be using C++14 if you have `make_unique`, if you are using C++11 then just spell the return type out explicitly.)

Comment: Seems simple enough. I don't see a point in using std::array since BaseX will require a vector anyway (size of objects container is unknown except to DerivedX). What would be the best way to define the BaseX constructor? I can get away with just `BaseX (vector<unique_ptr<Object>> v) : objects (move(v)) { }` as long as I redefine `objects` to hold pointers to non-const `Object`s, but that seems a bit off.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that the base member is `vector< unique_ptr<const Object> >` ... so just declare its constructor to take that and make `make_vec` return that (as I've edited the question to do).

Comment: Great, this is pretty clean!